# Let $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{X},\Sigma,\mu)$ Prove the transformation $A\to\int_Afd\mu$ for $A\in\Sigma$ is sigma additive.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{X},\Sigma,\mu)$ Prove the transformation $A\to\int_Afd\mu$ for $A\in\Sigma$ is sigma additive.

My try is the following
Defining the transformation  $\nu(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ and setting $f(A)_-=\max\{-\nu(A),0\},f(A)_+=\max\{\nu(A),0\}$.
$f(A)=f_+(A)-f(A)_-$ and $f(A)_-,f(A)_+$ are non-negative functions.
Assuming that $A=\biguplus_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ .
We know that $\int_A|f|=\int_A f_++\int_Af_-<\infty$ and therefore each integral is finite.
$\nu(A)=\nu(\biguplus A_i)=\int_{\biguplus(A_i)}f=\int_{\biguplus(A_i)}f_+-f_-\underset{(**)}{=}\int_{\biguplus(A_i)}f_+-\int_{\biguplus(A_i)}f_-\underset{(*)}{=}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{A_i}f_+-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{A_i}f_-=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{A_i}f_+-\int_{A_i}f_-=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{A_i}f_+-f_-=\sum\nu(A_i)$
(*) I've seen before the same statment for non-negative functions.
(**) is true because$\int_{A_i}f_+,\int_{A_i}f_-<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step (*) in your question is because of the monotone convergence theorem. The sequence of functions $1_{\cup_{i=1}^n A_i}f_+$ and $1_{\cup_{i=1}^n A_i}f_-$ are monotone and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}1_{\cup_{i=1}^n A_i}f_+ =1_A f_+, $ so by the monotone convergence theorem, you can "take the limit outside of the integral".

\begin{align}
\nu(A)d\mu=\int_{A}f d\mu &=\int_{A}f_+ -f_- d\mu\underset{(**)}{=}\int_{A}f_+ d\mu -\int_{A}f_- d\mu =\int_{\Omega} 1_{A}f_+-\int_{\Omega}1_{A}f_- \\
&=\int_{\Omega} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1_{\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i}f_+-\int_{\Omega} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1_{\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i}f_- \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{\Omega} 1_{A_i}f_+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} -\int_{\Omega}1_{A_i}f_-=...
\end{align}